# The problem about jquery toggle function

Tags: jquery, toggle

First I write a  pull down top menu in the html:

```
<div class="top-menu-contain">
    <div class="pull-button" ><a href="#">Show Me</a></div>
    <div class="pull-button"style="display: none;"><a href="#">Hide Me</a></div>
</div>
```

In default state ,the top menu at the top of the browser with "fixed" css property，and set the "top:-100px;",only show the pull button.Then I write the jquery code to achieve a effect that make the menu slide down:

```
    $('.pull-button a').toggle(function () {
        $('.top-menu-contain').animate({ top: '+=100px' }, 'slow');
    }, function () {
        $('.top-menu-contain').animate({ top: '-=100px' }, 'slow');
```

actully this work well, then I add a funtion that,when the menu slide down,the button could change from"Show Me" to "Hide Me",then I add this jquery code :
    **$("div.pull-button").toggle();**
So the total jquery code is:

```
 $('.pull-button a').toggle(function () {
        $('.top-menu-contain').animate({ top: '+=100px' }, 'slow');
        $("div.pull-button").toggle();
    }, function () {
        $('.top-menu-contain').animate({ top: '-=100px' }, 'slow');
        $("div.pull-button").toggle();
    });
```

However it doesn't work right now, the button could change ,it become slide down twice,then slide up twice

[here is the online case](http://jsfiddle.net/hh54188/7EPyS/7/)

So what wrong with my jquery code ?How can I achieve it in correct way?Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you have two `a`s here, which you're toggling between. What happens when you press the link is this:

- First click: First toggle block is executed for the first anchor.
- Second click: First toggle block is executed for the second anchor.
- Third click: Second toggle block is executed for the first anchor.
- Fourth click: Second toggle block is executed for the second anchor.

You can get around this by only using one anchor, and updating the text in it instead:

```
$('.pull-button a').toggle(function()
{
    $('.top-menu-contain').animate({ top: '+=100px' }, 'slow');
    $('div.pull-button > a').text("Hide Me");
}, function()
{
    $('.top-menu-contain').animate({ top: '-=100px' }, 'slow');
    $('div.pull-button > a').text("Show Me");
});
```

Answer (score 5):

## [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/reigel/7EPyS/11/)

jQuery

```
$('.pull-button a').toggle(function() {
    $('.top-menu-contain').animate({
        top: '+=100px'
    }, 'slow');
    $(this).text('Hide Me');
}, function() {
    $('.top-menu-contain').animate({
        top: '-=100px'
    }, 'slow');
    $(this).text('Show Me');
});
```

html

```
<div class="top-menu-contain">
    <div class="pull-button" ><a href="#">Show Me</a></div>
</div>
```